# Format hour and minute integers to HH:MM format (char*)

Tags: time, variables

In Arduino code, I'm calling the `getTextBounds()` and `print()` API methods on my TFT handler object which accepts `char*` parameters and I have two integers holding a specific time's hour and minute part, for example:

```
int _hour = 7;
int _minute = 30;
```

I need to construct a `char*` variable that holds this string: `07:30`.
What is the simplest way to do that?

I tried this:

```
char* timestr = (_hour < 10 ? '0' : '') + _hour + ':' + (_minute < 10 ? '0' : '') + _minute;
```

But it gives me two kind of errors:

```
error: empty character constant
error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want a `char *`, you want a character array, i.e. you have to
allocate the memory for the string, not only for a pointer. That being
said, you can build the string one character at a time like this:

```c
char timestr[6];
timestr[0] = '0' + _hour / 10;
timestr[1] = '0' + _hour % 10;
timestr[2] = ':';
timestr[3] = '0' + _minute / 10;
timestr[4] = '0' + _minute % 10;
timestr[5] = '\0';
```

Then you can use `timestr` just as you would use a `char*`.

**Edit 1**: If you are not too short on RAM, you could allocate the string
statically, and have the C runtime initialize the characters `':'` and
`'\0'` at program startup. Then you just have to set the four remaining
chars on each conversion:

```c
static char timestr[] = "--:--";  // initialized only once, with template
timestr[0] = '0' + _hour / 10;
timestr[1] = '0' + _hour % 10;
timestr[3] = '0' + _minute / 10;
timestr[4] = '0' + _minute % 10;
```

**Edit 2**: Maybe the “simplest”, in the sense “closest to what you had
in mind”, would be to use a `String` object:

```c
String timestr = String() + (_hour < 10 ? "0" : "") + _hour
    + ':' + (_minute < 10 ? "0" : "") + _minute;
```

You could `print()` that String directly, or retrieve the internal
`char*` with the `c_str()` method.

I added this method only for completeness. Although simple in the source
code, it would not be my first choice: it uses more memory, it is more
CPU-intensive and – what worries me most – it uses heap allocation,
which carries the risk of memory fragmentation.

Comment: That's one good answer! 
What if I would like to form this value: "03 Dec, 2016", where "Dec" comes from a char*[12] or char[12][3]? Should I manually set each piece of the timestr variable?

Comment: @papaiatis: Best option would probably be to use [strftime()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime), from `<time.h>`, but it is only available on recent releases of avr-libc. You will have to test, as I don't know whether a time.h-enabled avr-libc is shipped with the Arduino IDE. If you don't have `strftime()`, `sprintf_P()` is a reasonable fallback. C.f. KIIV's answer.

Comment: I ended up using your Edit1 solution. Thank you a lot for your efforts! :-)

Answer (score 1):

What about using `stdio.h`? I know, it eats up some flash space, but:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  int _hour = 3;
  int _minute = 9;
  char buff[14]; // in worst case 6digigts per integer, separator and string terminating char

  sprintf_P(buff, PSTR("%02d:%02d"), _hour, _minute); // format string resides in flash (it needs special version of sprintf.
  // sprintf(buff, "%02d:%02d", _hour, _minute); // usual variant, but format is stored in RAM (and Flash too)

  Serial.println(buff);
  delay(5000);
}
```